# Getting current working dir in git hook

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a commit-msg hook that has to derive some information based on where (dir) the user is committing from. Let's say that the user is currently operating from the following path: `/projects/projectx/backend/stuff/things/`, when they do `git commit`.

I want to be able to discern, for example, that the user is in `backend` so this is a commit related to `backend`. My issue here is that the ways I know to get directory info (pwd, rev-parse) don't work in this situation because they end up being executed out of the hooks dir.

The only other idea I could think of would be to look into the staged files, but I'd rather avoid that as it'll make things trickier.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Let's say that the user is currently operating from the following path: `/projects/projectx/backend/stuff/things/`, when they do git commit.* Why is it your concern from where the `git commit` is done? Are fine with committing files under `/projects/projectx/backend/` if the `git commit` is done from `/projects`? Your scenario sound weird to me, but it may be legit - please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Git.  Git intentionally changes into a consistent directory when running hooks to make it easy to write hooks and doesn't expose the original working directory.

In addition, the kind of workflow you're suggesting doesn't work for many users.  I almost always work out of the main root of the repository, and that will be the case for almost everyone who uses an IDE as well (I use Vim).  If you want to guess what kind of commit it is, you'll need to use some sort of data about what's being committed in order to do that.